# How to use JavaScript setTimeout() in this scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app, the `app.js` code retrieves a `sessionID` and a `userID` from the server side.

At the same time, my navigation controller is setting up a menu which also comes from the server side.

The problem is that my navigation controller is executing BEFORE the app.js routine. And the result is that my `sessionID` and `userID` variables are assigned yet.

Ideally, I would like to know how to get my `app.js` code to fire before anything.

However, in the meantime, I would like to use the JavaScript `setTimeout()` function to simulate a deferred call. Meaning, I only want to continue when my sessionID and userID vars are defined.

My app.js code (where the session and user vars are initialized):

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage', [
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ui.dashboard',
        'kendo.directives'       
    ]).run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userService',  init]);

    function init($rootScope, $state, userService) {
        $rootScope.rageSessionVars = {};
        $rootScope.$state = $state;

        userService.getInitParams().then(function (razorEnvJson) {
            $rootScope.rageSessionVars = razorEnvJson;
            userService.init(rzEnvJson).then(function (data) {
                var response = data.status;
                if (response.match(/SUCCESS/g)) {
                    userService.openUserSession(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
                        var sessionID = data.data[0];
                        $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID = sessionID;
                        $rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID = "bobmazzo1234";
                        console.log("sessionID = " + sessionID);
                                              
                        $rootScope.rageSessionVars.currDashboardName = "Default";
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

})();
```

The navigation-controller.js code (where the user and session vars are not defined yet):

```js
function activate() {            

  $timeout(getDashboards, 1000);    // give time for app.js to init vars    
 
}

function getDashboards() {
            // GET ALL DASHBOARDS VIA API.
            var timeout;
            if ($rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID == undefined) {
                ?? SHOULD I DO SOMETHING HERE IN CASE ???
            }
            var sid = $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID;
            var userId = $rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID; 
            dashboardcontext.getDashboards(sid, userId);
        }
```

Comment: You may want to look into [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) which is the more AngularJS'ish way of accomplishing this.

Comment: You might want to use promises for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$interval` in your controller to check every `x` number of milliseconds if the userID and sessionID have returned, like this:

```
var stop = $interval(function() {
    if ($rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID != undefined) {
        //SUCCESS CODE HERE - DON'T FORGET TO STOP THE INTERVAL!
        $interval.cancel(stop);
    }
}, 100);
```

I've used 100 milliseconds, change to suit your needs. [$interval API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: so I left my app.js as is, but I changed navigation-controller.js

Comment: Miles P - okay so I'll try your idea.

Comment: BINGO ! The $interval is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use watcher:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
    return $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== void 0) {
        foo();
    }
});
```

But i think you need use promises.